# How to only move rows from one dataframe to another where ID is not present in the second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, staging and permanent:

staging has daily ID's imported into it.

Permanent keeps records of all ID's.

I need to only append rows where ID's in staging are not present in permanent. Not sure how to create this logic.

Example:

Staging:

```
ID Date
0   20180202
1   20180202
```

Permanent:

```
ID Date
2   20180202
```

Logic I need would transform permanent df into this:

```
  ID Date
    0   20180202
    1   20180202
    2   20180202
```

Comment: append and concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

permanent_df = pd.concat([permanent_df , temp_df])
```